# Can't compile C++ function on my machine although it compiles fine using online compiler

Tags: c++, macos

I have a simple recursive Binary Search program in C++. The program compiles just fine using ideone: http://ideone.com/gMB96l

However, when I try to compile on my machine, using Xcode in OS X, it gives an error: control may reach end of non-void function.

It's also the same when I tried to compile using command line: `g++ RecursiveBinarySearch.cpp` and `./a.out`, it gives me: RecursiveBinarySearch.cpp:18:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Does anyone know why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static const int SIZE = 10;

int search(int arr[], int target, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    if (startIndex > endIndex) return -1;

    int midIndex = (startIndex + endIndex) / 2;

    if (target == arr[midIndex])
        return midIndex;
    else if (target < arr[midIndex])
        search(arr, target, startIndex, midIndex-1);
    else
        search(arr, target, midIndex+1, endIndex);
}

int main() {
    int arr[SIZE] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    cout << "3 is at index: " << search(arr, 3, 0, SIZE-1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No it does not compile fine with an online compiler. The online compiler just doesn't show you warnings, nor treats warnings as errors. If you want to use an online compiler, find one that lets you set your own flags, and use `-Wall -Werror`

Comment: Yes, that compiler was misleading. I should have not used it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code for `search` doesn't return a value unless `target == arr[midIndex]`.  You probably meant to `return` the value returned by your recursive calls to `search` i.e. `return search(arr, target, ...);`

Answer (score 1):

I see where you might be confused. Your logic is correct, however the compiler assumes that you do not have a return statement although it will be reached when *target=arr[midIndex]*

**Hense the warning**
*Control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]*

A quick (but ugly) fix will be to add a return statement at the end of the method which will never be reached.

Note in the future, when you encounter this error it is usually this issue.

Hope this helps